# Eclipse crashes JVM on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jvm, libsass

I've used this version of eclipse for over half a year without (too many) problems. However since a Tuesday the JVM crashes very frequently. If I start it from the command line I get the attached backtrace. It seems to indicate some problem in JVM.

The day before I started running into problems I've installed a new version of the JVM (was 8u171, became 8u181). But I've also started using a sass module in my pom file. Could that be the root cause of my problem or am I totally looking in the wrong direction?

Platform: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/java': free(): invalid pointer: 
0x00007f3521d16bc0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f36a72fb7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f36a730437a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f36a730853c]
/tmp/libjsass5866117610207413089/libjsass.so (_ZNSt6locale5_Impl16_M_install_facetEPKNS_2idEPKNS_5facetE+0x142)[0x7f3521a2d1a2]
/tmp/libjsass-5866117610207413089/libjsass.so(_ZNSt6locale5_ImplC1Em+0x1e3)[0x7f3521a2b273]
/tmp/libjsass- 5866117610207413089/libjsass.so(_ZNSt6locale18_S_initialize_onceEv+0x15)[0x7f3521a2c1e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xea99)[0x7f36a7a76a99]
/tmp/libjsass-5866117610207413089/libjsass.so(_ZNSt6locale13_S_initializeEv+0x21)[0x7f3521a2c231]
/tmp/libjsass-5866117610207413089/libjsass.so(_ZNSt6localeC1Ev+0x13)[0x7f3521a2c273]
/tmp/libjsass-5866117610207413089/libjsass.so(_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC2Ev+0xbc)[0x7f3521a2d4ec]
/tmp/libjsass-5866117610207413089/libjsass.so(+0x10ca2d)[0x7f352186fa2d]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x106ba)[0x7f36a7c956ba]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x107cb)[0x7f36a7c957cb]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x158e2)[0x7f36a7c9a8e2]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x10564)[0x7f36a7c95564]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x14da9)[0x7f36a7c99da9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0xf09)[0x7f36a764ef09]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x10564)[0x7f36a7c95564]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0x1571)[0x7f36a764f571]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(dlopen+0x31)[0x7f36a764efa1]
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(+0x92e7de)[0x7f36a6bb57de]
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JVM_LoadLibrary+0x15c)
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so(Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_00024NativeLibrary_load+0x138)[0x7f36a5949db8]
```

Comment: How did you install Java?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the SASS module.  It looks like the SASS module uses native code, and the native code appears to be on the callstack at the time if the JVM crash.   (Indeed, it looks like libjsass is directly responsible for the `free` call that is failing!)